# global variables not being found by array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I thought I understood scope and promises/synchronicity at this point, but I'm having a tricky time figuring out why this chunk of code keeps returning 'undefined' when I run it in node.js

```
var playerName; 
var teamName;
var tweets = [];

function composeTweet(){

    tweets = [ playerName + ' plays basketball for the ' + teamName,
               teamName + ' want to trade for ' + playerName,
               'what if ' + playerName + ' got traded to the ' + teamName];


    function getPlayer() {
        // some code, new promise, etc ... this stuff works locally ...
        playerName = 'Tim';
    }

    function getTeam(){
        // code, promise ... works here also ...
        teamName = 'Spurs';
    }

    getPlayerName().then(function(){
        return getTeamName();
    }).then(function(){
        // sendTweet();
        console.log(tweets[1]);

    }).catch(function(fromReject) {
        console.log('error?');
    });
}

composeTweet();
```

This ought to print:

> Spurs want to trade for Tim

But instead I get:

> undefined want to trade for undefined

Are playerName and teamName not global variables in this situation? Have I misunderstood how to use promises? How can I refer to global variables without using window.playerName (I don't think this works in node.js, correct?)?

I'm mostly new to programming so apologies if this is a duplicate!! Thanks much!!!

Comment: The code doesn't really make sense.. you never assign anything to `playerName` or `teamName`(the functions that set them are never called), so of course they're undefined.

Comment: The strings in `tweets` are created when the `composeTweet` function is called. If you later change the variable values it doesn't automatically update the strings that have already been created. You'll have to make them functions if you want to get the current values of the variables.

Comment: In other words if you do `var a = "Hello"; var b = a + " World!"; a = "Goodbye Cruel";` the value of `b` is still `"Hello World!"` – promises don't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you're setting `tweets` variable, `playerName` and `teamName` values are undefined since it's done before you're assigning any value to them.

You have to set `tweets` variable after `playerName` and `teamName` have desired values.

About variables scope and promises, the code is ok.